# Converting *.hs to llvm ir (*.ll) ---- Error: ghc: could not execute: opt --- on macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, haskell, llvm, macos-sierra

ghc -fllvm -keep-llvm-files -fforce-recomp hello.hs

[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( hello.hs, hello.o )

:
    Warning: Couldn't figure out LLVM version!
             Make sure you have installed LLVM
ghc: could not execute: opt

Although the .ll file is generated in the current directory but I still don't get the error.

Answer (score 2):

Need to set PATH, CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH

```
# export PATH=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH
# export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=$(llvm-config --includedir):$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
# export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(llvm-config --libdir):$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```